# Instant crash on throw statement with Qt5

Tags: c++, exception, mingw, qt5

When I try using Exceptions with Qt the application crashes instant on any throw statement, ignoring any `catch(...)`-clauses. This is the minimal code that causes the crash:

```
#include <QString>

int main ( ) {
    try {
        throw 1;
    } catch (...) {
        QString a;
    }
}
```

Without the `QString` it works fine, even if the library is included.

The Exception Code I get is

> 40000015

and the offset:

> 0000bb3f

I'm using **QtCreator 2.7.2** with **Qt 5.1.0** and **mingw 4.8** (the version shipped with QtCreator).
I used windows 8 for my builds.

After some research in the web I tried to add the `CONFIG+=exceptions` flag to the *.pro-file and still got the crash.
When I read that Qt can be build without exceptions (whatever that means) I checked the default values as I'm using the pre-compiled version shipped with the QtCreator; this one should be built including exceptions.

I checked the temp code after the pre-compiler and the pre-compiler didn't change anything for the main function.

When I tried debugging the code I noticed that it didn't execute any line after the throw statement, it really crashes exactly there.

I'm still a beginner with Qt; is this a problem for this built of Qt? should I just get a newer one? Or did I miss some configs I could change in order to get it working?

**EDIT:** After Frank Osterfeld asked me to I tried with several other classes. Here are my findings:

- working as expected:

  - `std::string`
  - `QPoint`
  - `QChar`
  - `QDate`
  - `QMessageLogger`
- crashing:

  - `QString`
  - `QByteArray`
  - `QDir`
  - `QException`
  - `QFile`
  - `QRegularExpression`
  - `QSet<int>`
  - `QTimer`

Comment: Works fine with gcc 4.7.2 (Linux), both with Qt 4.8.5 and Qt 5.1.1. It's shouldn't be necessary to configure anything regarding exceptions in the .pro file. Also I can't imagine that this is a generic Qt issue. Maybe something mingw-specific. Check if it also happens with other classes than QString (say, QByteArray or just a QPoint)

Comment: Would be also interesting to know if it works with std::string.

Comment: std::string works perfectly well.
QByteArray crashes, too; but QPoint works just as expected

Comment: Tried some other classes, too; updated Question with them

Comment: You don't have other versions of Qt or MinGW in your system, do you?  If so, uninstall them. There are 3 different "flavours" of MinGW with different exception handling mechanisms: DWARF-2, SEH, SJLJ. If you have multiple versions of the libraries or compilers, cross-linking between incompatible versions might occur, causing strange crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll double check this; but AFAIK I don't.

Comment: Ok I checked and saw I have a Backup of a portable Codeblocks-Installation with MinGW-Compiler on my system. They are not really installed on the system itself but just a backup of an USB-stick installation.
Anyway when I removed it nothing changed for the Exception-problem

Answer (score 1):

Qt application crashes instant on any throw statement - I found this happens when application compiled with flag `-static`.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -static
```

Environment: Qt 5.5.1, mingw 32bit runtime, Windows 8.

Comment: Interesting find. I'm not sure if this would have fixed my problem as it worked after a re-install of the machine; but I'm not sure if I installed Qt somehow different after the re-install. Unfortunately I cannot try it anymore.

It would be interesting to know if the problem occurs on your machine with my code from the question and experiment if it works with i.e. `QPoint` while it fails with a `QString`. +1 for the find.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by reinstalling the whole Computer.
I had to do this anyway and it fixed the problem when I downloaded the new Version of QtCreator (3.0.0).

Probably it would have been enough to reinstall Qt though.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really the "solution"...  The whole thing certainly is bizarre though, and I ran into a very similar problem I couldn't quite figure out either (see my answer).

Comment: Well, it is not an easy solution, but it fixed my problem. Therefore I would consider it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt 5.2.1.

I ran into a situation where this kind of throw would cause the application to crash (but not always!):

```
try{ throw; } catch(...){ }
```

I replaced that with

```
try{ throw 1; } catch(...){ }
```

And it fixed the problem.  Not sure why or when exactly this change was needed, but this might help someone out...

Comment: A throw statement without consecutive Object (or "thing") to throw is [only allowed within a catch-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) and re-throws the catched exception. So you may use `try { /* some code */ } catch (...) { throw; }`, but never `throw;` outside a catch.

Comment: Well to be precise it is allowed outside, but will instantly call `std::terminate` in that case.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.  The only problem is that I'm pretty sure this was working under some circumstances... I'd have to review the code.  Would it work if inside the try{} a function was called which threw an exception?  Or, if this was found inside another function containing a try/catch?

Comment: It will work only, if the `throw;` is somehow inside a `catch` block. I guess it _might_ work if the `throw;` is inside a function called from a catch-block, I have not tried this though. But I can imagine very well that this could lead to very strange behaviour.

Comment: Another thought: If someone installed a non-default handler for `std::terminate`, the code might not lead to a crash. I would consider this very bad practice though and cant't imagine a situation where this is a good idea.